# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'Datos' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, context

Creé un context para describir el state de la aplicación tal como está en el código

```
import React,{createContext, useState} from 'react';


export const FormularioContext = createContext();


const FormularioProvider = (props)=>{


   const [Datos, setDatos] = useState({

    monto : '',
    opcion : '',
    porciento : '',
    plazo: ''
})

    return(


        <FormularioContext.Provider
        
            value={{

            Datos,
            setDatos

            }}

            >

            {props.children}
            
       </FormularioContext.Provider>

    )

}


export default FormularioProvider
```

Y en este componente lo estoy consumiendo

```
import React,{useContext} from 'react';
import FormularioContext from '../Context/FormularioContext'



const Formulario = () => {


    const {Datos, setDatos} = useContext(FormularioContext) // tome un context que es FormularioContext 


    const { monto  ,opcion ,    porciento ,  plazo  } = Datos

    const ReadDates = (e)=>{

        e.preventDefault();


        setDatos({

            ...Datos,
            [e.target.name] : e.target.value



        })

    }


    return (

        <>
        
        <h3 className="Titulo" >Prestamos Hnos Frias y Asociados</h3>

        <div className="cotizadorFlex">


              <form>


            <div className="cotizadorhijo">
              
             <h1>Monto a tomar</h1>
                <input 
                    className="u-full-width input1" 
                    type="number" 
                    placeholder="Ejemplo: 3000" 
                    name="monto"
                    value={monto}
                    onChange={ReadDates}
                />
            </div>
            <div>

                <h1> Intereses</h1>

            <input 

            className="u-full-width input1"
            type="number"
            placeholder="Porcierto de Interes"
            name="porciento"
            value={porciento}
            onChange={ReadDates}


            />

        <h1>Opcion de Pago</h1>

            <input  
            
            className="radius"
            type="radio"
            name="opcion"
            value={opcion}
            
           // checked={opcion === "Quincenal"}
           onChange={ReadDates}
         
            
            
            />Quincenal


            <input  
             className="radius"
            type="radio"
            name="opcion"
            value={opcion}
           // checked={opcion === "Mensual"}
           onChange={ReadDates}
            
            />Mensual


                <h1>Plazo para Pagar</h1>
                <select 
                    className="u-full-width input1"
                    name="plazo"
                    onChange={ReadDates}
                    value={plazo}
                >
                    <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
                    <option value="3">3 meses</option>
                    <option value="6">6 meses</option>
                    <option value="12">12 meses</option>
                    <option value="24">24 meses</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input 
                    type="submit" 
                    value="Calcular" 
                    className="button-primary u-full-width" 
                />

            </div>

            </form>
        </div>


        </>

    )
}

export default Formulario
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es el siguiente:

```
import FormularioContext from '../Context/FormularioContext'
```

Estas importando el `FormularioContext` como un componente, deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
import { FormularioContext } from '../Context/FormularioContext'
```

Significa que estas obteniento la variable de forma individual (No por defecto).

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso ese error me dió por que en un componente, que es de la página, no estaba llamando al : es decir me quedó así:

```
<Layout>
        <ClienteContextProvider>
        <PersonaContextProvider>

            <div className="panel">
                <div className="panel-heading">
                    Clientes
                </div>
                <div className="box">

                    <ToolbarCLiente/>

                    <TableCliente/>
                </div>
                <Modal>
                    <FormCliente/>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        </PersonaContextProvider>
        </ClienteContextProvider>
    </Layout>
```